# Git : reload .gitconfig file from the bash console

Tags: bash, git, console, git-bash, git-config

I want to quickly test my changes in my user `.gitconfig` file without closing and reopening the console. Is there a way to load it again, much like `source .bashrc` would reload the bash config ?

EDIT : `source ~/.gitconfig` didn't work, not that this surprises me, but just saying.

Comment: `.gitconfig` is not cached anywhere, you don't need to reload it. Just edit it and it'll be used on the next `git` command. You cannot `source` it because `source` is for shell config files and `.gitconfig` is a git config.

Comment: Try this command to make sure your config file is being read: `git config --list --show-origin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git automatically reads the `.gitconfig` file each time you run a Git command. Therefore, any changes you make to the file will take effect immediately without needing to reload or restart anything. Just save your changes, and the next time you run a Git command, the updated configuration will be used.

Comment: Ya fished for it, ya found it- ya gettin it !